# Find square matrix $A$ of minimal order such that $\vec{X}_0'(t)=A\cdot \vec{X}_0(t)$

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I have been studying ODE's for a while, and I'm about to finish the course. I enjoyed it absolutely, until Linear Algebra came around. I understand that it's a crucial part of solving specific kinds of ODE's, but I never manage to solve such problems.  Here is one of them, which I tried to solve, but to no avail:

Let $\vec{X}(t)$ be a vector of $n\in\mathbb{N}$ functions of the variable $t$, such that $\vec{X}$$'(t)$ is the vector of the derivatives of the corresponding functions.  Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a matrix of constant real numbers, and let $v_1,v_2,v_3,\cdots,v_n\in\mathbb{R}$ be $n$ constant and real numbers.

Given the vector:

$$\vec{X}_0(t)=\vec{W}(t)+\vec{V}e^{2t}$$

Such that:

$$\vec{W}(t)=\begin{pmatrix} \sin(t)+\cos(t) \\ \cos(t)-\sin(t) \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}\quad \&\quad \vec{V}=\begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \\ v_3 \\ \vdots \\ v_n \end{pmatrix}$$

We would like to find a matrix $A$ with $n$ *lowest as possible*, that meets the aforesaid requirements, such that $\vec{X}_0(t)$ is a solution of the system $\vec{X}$$'(t)=A\cdot\vec{X}(t)$.

I'd guess diagonalization is the key here, but I don't know how to continue from there. Also, there might be a chance that $A$ doesn't even exist. If so, please help me understand why.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Observe that

$$\vec{X}_{0}\left(t\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\begin{matrix}1-i\\1+i\\0\\\vdots\\0\end{matrix}\right)e^{it}+\frac{1}{2}\left(\begin{matrix}1+i\\1-i\\0\\\vdots\\0\end{matrix}\right)e^{-it}+\left(\begin{matrix}v_{1}\\v_{2}\\v_{3}\\\vdots\\v_{n}\end{matrix}\right)e^{2t}$$

You also know the equation $\vec{X}^{\prime}=A\vec{X}$ has a solution

$$\vec{X}=C_{1}\vec{u}_{1}e^{\lambda_{1}t}+\dots+C_{n}\vec{u}_{n}e^{\lambda_{n}t}$$

where $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ has $n$ eigenvectors $u_{i}$ and eigenvalues $\lambda_{i}$ and $C_{i}\in\mathbb{R}$ are constants.

Comparing those statements, can you say what are (some) of the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $A$ in your case? How many are there? What is the minimal size of $A$ as a consequence? Can you find $A$ in this case using $P^{-1}AP=D$ from linear algebra?

Comment: First - thank you! Now I understand that I need to build $P$ with the 3 vectors you wrote (maybe more), find its inverse, and let $D$ be the diagonal matrix with $i,-i,2$ in its diagonal (maybe there are more?). Then $A=PDP^{-1}$. But I don't know if a matrix $3\times 3$ would do. Maybe I need more?

Comment: You should calculate this. It will turn out to be real since you have a real eigenvalue and also one with its complex conjugate.